# Silverstripe 4 - CSS and JS Requirements. How/what populates the /resources directory?

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I have a SS3.x module that I have forked, pulled down from it's fork via composer, and started porting to SS4. So far so good, except when it comes to Requirements.

I'm using the Requirements format found in existing code in another module, which has a colon-separated format as follows:

```
Requirements::javascript('company/mymodule:javascript/SortableUploadField.js');
```

This file exists in the module at /vendor/company/mymodule/javascript/SortableUploadField.js. However on page load, I have a 404 in console as SS is looking for this file at /resources/company/mymodule/css/SortableUploadField.css. And this does not exist.

I added the following to my composer.json file for the module as I saw other modules doing this:

```
"extra": {
    "installer-name": "sortableuploadfield",
    "expose": [
        "css",
        "javascript"
    ]
},
```

And ran a composer update. But the /resources directory does not appear for this module (other modules are there). And I can't find any information online on how this is supposed to work.

**Edit**: As a sidenote, I wonder if the [documentation for Requirements](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/templates/requirements) is misleading? It omits this caveat with modules and mention of the resources directory at all. If that documentation is meant only to convey the process for working with JS/CSS in normal mysite development, then it is just a bit confusing because the code samples us  everywhere. Which wouldn't be a direct url to something in /vendor, surely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found this after tracing code that basically used the /resources directory. Short answer to my query is simply running

**composer vendor-expose**

This calls the VendorExposeTask that does this copying. The only other place I found this task being used is on VendorPlugin install method. So I assume that other than the above command, the only way SS actually does this on your behalf is on initial install of a module.